# Dev Story images are stretched for "Other" items

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

When I add an *Other* item to my dev story with an image, the image will be stretched to fill the item. This stretching does not occur for images in the *Blogs or Videos* item. This seems inconsistent and it's nice to be able to upload small images for items so they take up less space.

[image: Option vs Blogs with same small image]

Steps to reproduce:

1. In the Dev Story under *Add a new item*, click "Other".
2. Type "asdf" for the *Category*.
3. Type "asdf" for the *Title*.
4. Click the *Click to add an image* area.
5. Upload this image: [image: small test image]
6. Select "January, 2016" for *Date started*.

If the bug still exists, the image will be stretched. If the bug is fixed, the image will have its original size.

To see the image as it should appear when the bug is fixed, add it to a *Blogs or Videos* item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks so much for reporting this! It should be fixed now :).